# Django Multiselect Filed showing List Index Out Of range Error in Window

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-multiwidget, django-multiselectfield

I was working with Django and it's throwing an error `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` and the same code is working fine on Linux production, I used `pip install django-multiselectfield` for multiselect in Django, I am using this `DATA= (('0', 'Small'),('1', 'Medium'),('2', 'Large,)` and my field name is `clients = MultiSelectField(choices=DATA, null = True, blank= True)`this, but this is not working and throwing me list index out of range error on window power shell, please let me know how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Please share the whole error message and the code where it occurs.